# iOS Read Json from web and display to tableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

What I am trying to do is read a json file on the web (I know the connection to this aspect is working) and then get some file contents to display on my tableView.

I was able to do this fine in another example but I'm not sure what the problem is now.

**JSON File:**

```
{
"entry":
[
{"Current Date":"Tuesday June 22 2011","Time Period":"00:00 - 06:45,"},
{"Current Date":"Tuesday June 23 2011","Time Period":"00:00 - 07:22"}
]
}
```

**Button that fetches the JSON file from the web:**

```
- (IBAction)getJsonButton:(id)sender {

[array removeAllObjects];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://LinkToWhereJSONfileIsLocated/"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
}
```

**Here's where I think I'm having my problem (must be my logic or syntax):**

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *arrayOfEntry = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"entry"];

for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) {
    NSString *currDate = [diction objectForKey:@"Current Date"];

    [array addObject:currDate];

}

[[self myTableView]reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the program builds successfully but doesn't show any data in the table when i press my button and that's my dilemma. Thanks.

Comment: "Xcode Read JSON from web" - Xcode does not read JSON, and you should **not** tag this question with `Xcode`. Be it iOS or OS X programming, you don't need Xcode for that, and the Xcode tag should be only used for questions about that particular IDE itself.

Comment: You should do some basic diagnostics and let us know what you find. For example, create a `NSString *requestAsString = [[NSString stringWithData:request encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];` and then do a `NSLog` of that string. Also, do a NSLog of `allDataDictionary`. Etc. You need to go through this code, line by line, and identify what the results are so you can diagnose where you're going astray.

Comment: I just modified the file so I can get at least one piece of the data to display before moving on to the actual file. This is what the file is ultimately going to look like:

[{"Current Date":"Tuesday   June      28 2010","Time Period":"00:00 - 06:45","Transaction Processed":"5,888","Approved":"5,525","Standing App":"0","Approval Rate":"93.83","Resp Time":"0.12","Date Prev":"Tuesday   June      21 2011","Transaction Processed Prev":"6,170","Approved Prev":"5,778","Standing App Prev":"0","Approval Rate Prev":"93.64","Resp. Time Prev":"0.13","Difference":"-       282~,"},{more fields},{etc}]

Comment: The JSON format is curious. In your comment above, you have a slightly different format (just an array of dictionaries). Obviously the code would change to accommodate that. Still, you really should go through your code line-by-line, and figure out where it's going wrong. There's nothing obviously wrong with the code, but there could be a ton of problems. URL mistyped? JSON misformatted? Typo in a key name? Bug in your table view code? So many possibilities and it's impossible for us to diagnose. You have to look line by line to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: [Step Through Code in the Source Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW27)

Comment: Got it work, it was a URL issue, thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Had to be something simple. :) Glad you solved your issue.

Comment: The fact that it was a URL issue points out the fact that you didn't implement the connection:didFailWithError: method -- you should, it would have told you that you had a bad url.

Comment: No I had, but it wasn't that the URL was bad it was a matter of where I had placed the file on the web that it was pushing the file to be downloaded and not really readable, so I'm guessing thats why the error didn't go off.

Comment: @user1832095: Will u please tell me how you have put that file on web please ? Because I just want to know...thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick guess, try calling `reloadData` method on main thread.

Comment: URL issue, everything else was right, thanks for taking the time to help though!